# Facebook App Center does not accept "Detailed Description" translations

Tags: facebook, translation

I keep geting an error for de Detailed Description translations to two of the languages in my app. The error is:

> App detailed description: Please remove extra characters, words, or URLs. Please fix any misspelled words, grammatical errors, excessive punctuation/symbols, or non-standard capitalization.

And there's also a note:

"Portuguese and German App Detailed Descriptions are not translated correctly. Please review the whole section and correct it."

I have checked both languages for all the stuff listed on the error, and found none of it. Also I checked it for correctness and it's ok. Still, App Center would not accept the translations I provided.

Any ideas?

Comment: _“Any ideas?”_ – How about: Show us your (English?) original app description, and the translations …?